# TCP - сервер на python

Tags: python, парсер, tcp

Python учу совсем недавно, пытаюсь найти работу стажером. На очередной отклик прислали тестовое задание: необходимо сделать `tcp` сервер, который распознаёт заданный формат данных и отображает его в требуемом формате.

Обязательна запись данных во внешний файл. Интерфейс и способ отображения на выбор разработчика.

Формат данных:

```
BBBBxNNxHH:MM:SS.zhqxGGCR
```

где `BBBB` - номер участника, `x` - пробельный символ, `NN` - id канала,  `HH` - Часы, `MM` - минуты, `SS` - секунды, `zhq` - десятые сотые тысячные, `GG` - номер группы, `CR` - «возврат каретки» (закрывающий символ).

Пример данных: `0002 C1 01:13:02.877 00[CR]`. Выводим «спортсмен, нагрудный номер `BBBB` прошёл отсечку `NN` в «время»" до десятых, сотые и тысячные отсекаются. Только для группы `00`.

Для остальных групп данные не отображаются, но пишутся в лог полностью.

Статьи почитал, документацию тоже, но в голове осело маловато.

Может посоветуете чего ещё почитать, чтобы было близко к теме.

Comment: tcp - это сокеты, смотрите в сторону `socket.socket()`, мой hello world по теме: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/7ac07d81a97d1b63391282e74989f145d61461f7/socket__tcp__examples/hello_world/server.py#L18 . А ту строку парсите. Я бы сделал через регулярные выражения, но можно просто через индексы вытаскивать значения из строки

Comment: Тут вам надо поучить регулярные выражения чтобы парить пришедшие данные

Answer (score 4):

Ну... раз вы так ставите вопрос... Я бы сначала разделил ТЗ на подзадачи. То есть:

1. Создать простейший сервер TCP  и клиента для тестов и проверить их взаимодействие на простейшем примере. [Например](https://habr.com/ru/post/149077/)
2. Настроить клиента на отправку данных в нужном нам виде, сервер на прием этих данных.
3. В сервере пишем блок парсера, данные разбираем на запчасти и обрабатываем
4. Пишем блок вывода данных (в формате... ну как в ТЗ предложили)
5. Пишем блок сохранения данных в лог-файл.

Вот такой план... был бы у меня. :-)